# What is the best way to load data from database without page reload?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my website, I am trying to load product items without refreshing the whole page. I managed to do that with `setInterval` and `load()`. However I come across a problem.
Product items contains individual images. But since I set the interval to 3 seconds, it re-downloads all of the needed resources, and I think that that is a problem because users with slow connections will be annoyed. I simulated a slow connection on dev tools just to see what would happen.

This is the result. It takes time to reload the images or the whole product_item page.

[image: slow connection simulation]

these are my codes

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#product_item_inner').load('components/product_item.php');
        }, 3000);
    })
</script>
```

Now I wonder what is the best way to load data efficiently.
I do not want to use `setInterval` or `AutoPageRefresh`.
Is there a better way to achieve this?
I hope someone could suggest me something. I have search in the internet and so far this is the only code that works in fetching data without page refresh.

Comment: best way? initially load 12, then use intersection observer to load 12 more, all returning json and building the dom from that, over ajax obviously.. its called lazy loading. Using a timer to blindly load more, you might as well just load them all, also the timer is not going to stop, plus will perhaps cause a delay in navigation if they stack up

Comment: Ensuring the images are cacheable will help

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I mean best way to fetch data from database without refreshing the page. But it's nice to be aware of _Intersection observer_ and _lazy loading_. Might be useful in the future. I'm not aware of any of those at this moment. Just a beginner here :)

Comment: AJAX is the best way for your problem. As this got answered: what's the real problem? How is the given question related to PHP?

Comment: The real problem is fetching data from database without page refresh. I never tried ajax before and the only solution I know in fetching data is using PHP. So I thought I might include PHP as tag. I tried ajax. and so far, the script above is the only that works and that I found. Now that I am aware about ajax, I will try searching for it to further find a better way to solve this problem.